# Why do I have 0 degrees of freedom for my group mean variables in my mixed model? nlme package

Tags: r, mixed-model, degrees-of-freedom, lme4-nlme

I am trying to run a mixed effects model in the R package 'nlme'. I have 3 groups and 294 observations, and am using the following model:

```
 model1<-lme(shy ~ int + ind + grpint +grpind, random =~1 | group, 
             data = dt, control=list(opt="nlmimb"))
```

The variables 'grpint' and 'grpind' are vectors of group means for the 'int' and 'ind' variables. (I am running this test to see if individual scores in 'int' or 'ind' still significantly predict group differences in 'shy' over and above group scores.)

When looking at my output (below), I am very confused as to why my group variables have 0 df. Did I enter something incorrectly? Is this still acceptable when attempting to test my research question?

Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge and expertise!

```
 Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: dt 
        AIC      BIC    logLik
   93.80127 119.4663 -39.90063

 Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | group
         (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:  0.07421543 0.2755107

 Fixed effects: shyness ~ interdependent + independent + grpint + grpind 
                     Value Std.Error  DF    t-value p-value
 (Intercept)     2.5677638  37.76813 289  0.0679876  0.9458
 interdependent -0.0523904   0.05406 289 -0.9691753  0.3333
 independent     0.1623483   0.05329 289  3.0462865  0.0025
 grpint          1.5382962  23.23831   0  0.0661965     NaN
 grpind         -1.6347691   7.78430   0 -0.2100085     NaN
  Correlation: 
                (Intr) intrdp indpnd grpint
 interdependent  0.000                     
 independent     0.000 -0.061              
 grpint         -0.998 -0.002  0.000       
 grpind          0.979  0.000 -0.007 -0.991

 Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
 -4.39909336 -0.43557519 -0.09616286  0.48480368  3.05524916 

 Number of Observations: 294
 Number of Groups: 3
```